# Quick fix for terminal rules in xtext

Tags: java, eclipse, dsl, xtext

my DSL grammer look like (only necessary part is displayed )

```
assemblerProgram: // standard way of defining model
content += CommandLine+
;

CommandLine: 
ControlInstructions | Pointaddress ;

Pointaddress:
name = POINTINGADD

terminal POINTINGADD:('_')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')? ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
```

where POINTINGADD is a terminal rule which say that name should starts with "_".

Now I want to implement a quick fix for this terminal rule. is it possible? and which path should I follow?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Except for the missing semi-colon in line 8 I can't see a problem that needs to be fixed?

Comment: what i exactly want is, whenever I enter a word without underscore  it should provide a quick fix, the same name starting with underscore

Comment: Ah, that one. I see.

Comment: Do you have any idea which way to go?

Comment: in this case you would loosen the terminal rule to leave out the underscore and add a semantic validation for the name + a quickfix.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I have loosen the terminal rule and inserted a validation check and then quickfix. It is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement a "semantic" quickfix (i.e., one that operates on the model rather than on text), it's probably better to have a more lenient grammar, which does accept names without the leading underscore, then create a validation that complains about this and assigns a specific error code, which can finally be used to trigger the [quickfix](http://ttps://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/304_ide_concepts.html#quick-fixes).

Alternatively, when dealing with syntax errors indeed, the documentation recommends to use [ISyntaxErrorMessageProvider](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/v2.8.0/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext/src/org/eclipse/xtext/parser/antlr/ISyntaxErrorMessageProvider.java), but I haven't yet used this approach.

Comment: I have implemented the first technique and its working. the second technique looks like cumbersome, so i didn't apply that. Thanks alot.